# Serial Port not working on Surface Book

Tags: serial-port, usb, hardware

I have a Microsoft Surface Book that I've dual booted Linux Mint on. I'm writing a program that needs to read in data from a serial port, but my serial ports don't seem to be working. The behavior is consistent across Mint and Windows (Testing done through Cygwin). It gets a bit of data the first 2-5 seconds that the device is plugged in (viewing the data through screen, same thing happens if I just use pyserial to print data incoming from serial port), then nothing.

What could be happening? I think I've isolated the problem to the serial ports - the Surface Book has 2 USB ports and the same thing happens on both of them, and I've tested the hardware that I'm plugging into it on 2 other computers (One Linux and one Mac OS), and it works fine on both of those.

Comment: What's the hardware adapter for USB to serial? The drivers for these matter a lot. I've had the best luck with FTDI based adapters.

Comment: *"I'm writing a program..."* -- So you decided that it's a HW issue rather than suspect your new code?

Comment: @sawdust yes because as I said I tested it in screen and it worked the same way as my code did, and running the same test on a friend's laptop with screen it worked fine. Also my code works fine on that laptop (and 2 others)

Comment: @Phil Not sure what you mean - the specific setup is a pixhawk with a microusb -> USB A plugged into the serial port of the surface book. I'll give a shot at updating the USB drivers though, good thought.

Comment: Your indiscriminate use of jargon and plain English is confusing.  E.G. *"bit of data"*, *"viewing the data through screen"* (is "screen" a program?).  So you're saying that your tablet has RS232 ports when you write *"serial port of the surface book"*?  FYI USB ports should never be called *"serial ports"*.

Comment: @sawdust - Sorry! I'm not really a hardware person. screen is a program on unix that can view/send packets that I use to quickly see if/what data is coming from USB. For example, I run the command "screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200" to see packets coming from /dev/ttyACM0 at baudrate 115200. The surface boo does not have RS232 ports, I'm referring to usbserial I believe which emulates a serial port over USB (I'm just learning that distinction now, I'd been thinking that this was serial all along until now - I'm still very much a beginner at this)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @sawdust on the confusion. Surface Books don't have RS-232 ports i.e. serial ports. So your pixhawk has a built in USB stack. What device is it registering as on the Surface? i.e. if you check the Windows Device list, it should appear there if it has a valid driver. Given is works on Linux and OSX, I highly suspect a driver problem on Windows.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - the Surface book dual boots Windows and Linux, and it works on neither one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting the computer replaced on warranty for an unrelated issue months later, and what do you know, on the new computer the serial ports work fine. That indicates to me some sort of hardware problem, given that the issue persisted across OS's.

Answer (score 1):

Your MS Surface, seemingly, has a yellow triangle exclamation mark icon (over the adapter icon) without any driver to install/download. And properties in the device status box window say `This device cannot start. (Code 10)` or `A device which does not exist was specified`. Right?

If it's so you should wait for an update from MS. It's notorious problem.

Comment: This does not answer the question - sorry if it was unclear, but I dual boot Windows and Linux Mint on the Surface Book. The problem therefore is very unlikely to be a Windows driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

see Arduino examples for serial port communication - search google:

- arduino serial c++
- arduino serial c#
- arduino serial c++ linux

the point is to open port properly you need to open a file, not a port. not with usual c - assembly write to port code.

---

another option you are using an unintentionally bought fake USB to serial cable with a Fake PL2303 chip
then you need to install the old version of the driver.
search in google:

Fake PL2303 + your os name:

install driver Fake PL2303 windows 10

---

another option is maybe it conserves energy and closes the port because it feels it is unused.

in windows> device manager,> properties of a device - usually USB root hub > power management - allow the computer to turn off this device to save power - uncheck it.

https://superuser.com/questions/408683/why-my-usb-mouse-gets-suspended-after-3-seconds-of-inactivity

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usbcoreblog/2013/11/08/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-my-usb-device-doesnt-charge-or-it-disconnects-and-reconnects-frequently/

---

also, you could look in windows events - to see what happens. usually, failures like this are registered in the events log.

---

an unlikely option is it consumes too much current, like a short circuit.  and the device protection circuit shuts the chip off.  also probably it does not have such circuit. one possibility is to try with an external powered hub.

---

the most probable of these is the power saving mechanism

Comment: As mentioned, the device I'm using works on computers other than my own using the same methods. Also, the problem persists across OS's

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem - came across the solution on another site. The USB 3 ports on Surface Book aren't compatible with something or other to do with Com Port but running the device through a cheap USB hub solved my problem straight away and it was instantly recognised by the Arduino IDE